# expected '{' before 'case' switch case error in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have to make a program that displays the value for given expressions in C++. So, I decided to make a switch/case and use it for calculating and displaying them! However, I have some problem with an error I get, which I can't solve...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        int x = 5, y = 8;

        switch case(i){

            case 0:
            x+=(++x)+(x++);
            cout << "x+=(++x)+(x++) = " << x << endl;
            break;

            case 1:
            x+=++y;
            cout << "x+=++y = " << x << endl;
            break;

            case 2:
            x+=2*x++;
            cout << "x+=2*x++ = " << x << endl;
            break;

            case 3:
            x=--y+x--+x;
            cout << "x=--y+x--+x = " << x << endl;
            break;

            case 4:
            x-=(-y)%3;
            cout << "x-=(-y)%3 = " << x << endl;
            break;

            case 5:
            y+=--y+x-y%x--;
            cout << "y+=--y+x-y%x-- = " << y << endl;
            break;

            case 6:
            x+=++y---x+y++;
            cout << "x+=++y---x+y++ = " << x << endl;
            break;

            default:
            cout << "Wrong value." << endl;
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The line which returns an error is

```
switch case(i){
```

And also, there are two warnings, variables 'x' and 'y' not being used, but I do use them in each case. Should I separately declare them in each case? They must have the value 5 and 8 as beginning value for each case.

Comment: At least try to [lookup the syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).

Comment: Also, I am quite sure x+=(++x)+(x++); is undefined behaviour because it modifies the same variable multiple times without a sequence point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, `switch case` is not legal C.
You need `switch(i)`.

Comment: Ouch.. such a bad mistake, I think I overlooked it.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
switch case(i){
```

is not a valid syntax.

It should be

```
switch(i) {
```

Since the inner case conditions are not visible because of this error, it is giving you the warnings, `variables 'x' and 'y' not being used`

Answer (score 2):

I think you've been raised on some other language.  The correct syntax is:

```
switch(i) {
   // case statements
   // optional default statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please check C++ switch statement syntax:

```
switch (i) {
    ....
}
```